# Randomly unable to access 1 network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive

I have one user who randomly can't access one of her mapped network drives.  She has 6 network drives mapped to shares on the same Windows 2008 r2 file server.  No other users are reporting this problem.  When the problem happens with her P:\ she can access the other drives without a problem.  The problem is resolved by a simple restart.  Her drives are mapped automatically via  Kixtart logon script GPO, the first command of the script is to disconnect all drives. This seems like it's happening a couple times a day with no discernible pattern.  She sent me the screenshot below which shows that Windows 8.1 thinks her P:\ has the same amount of space as her C:\

[image: Drives]

Comment: When the problem is showing, what does `net use` report?

Comment: Is her P drive mapped to the same directory as yours?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Event Viewer of that workstation and look under System errors and warnings. Look for things that you have the response of "well, that shouldn't be there." Fix those items. 
Repeat on the server that the user is connected to. 
Also, make sure the user's password isn't password and does not contain the word password.